# Rewriting of url in .htaccess doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a file in my directory countries.php which will be use by my client page (index.html) to get list of countries. So far it does work when I make the request using this url `localhost/api/countries` but when I do `localhost/api/countries/cuba` for example, it still get the list of all countries 
but if I do  `localhost/api/countries?name=cuba` it returns the stuff that i need.

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ countries.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
```

it removes the .php extension but it doesnt rewrite the parameters

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please can you make it clear what you want to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule runs only when the request is for an existent file or dir, remove the conditions  or try this

```
RewriteRule (.*) /countries.php?name=$1
```